# setState works every second call

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple form that sets the state of `passwordInvalid`.

The state is initially:

`this.state = { email: '', passwordInvalid: false };`

and the `email` part is fine, it updates when I submit my form.

The function that changes the `passwordInvalid` is:

```
passwordValidator = (email) => {
    this.setState(() => {
      if (email === 'test') {
        this.setState({ passwordInvalid: true });
      }
      else {
        this.setState({ passwordInvalid: false });
      }
    })
  }
```

And is called like so:

```
  mySubmitHandler = (event) => {
    this.passwordValidator(this.state.email);
    if (this.state.passwordInvalid) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Email: '" + this.state.email + "' is invalid.");
    }
    else {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Email address submitted: " + this.state.email);
    }
  }
```

I have read some of the documentation:

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

I've tried a number of variations of setting the state, but I just can't quite seem to get it to update with each call; it only works on the second call.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/L9jrhodt/)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use setState in setState, I think what you should do is like this:

```
passwordValidator = email => {
  if (email === "test") {
    this.setState({ passwordInvalid: true });
  } else {
    this.setState({ passwordInvalid: false });
  }
};
```

Comment: you can use `setState` in `setState` but it doesn't make much sense. The crux of the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @marzelin yes, its because setstate is asynchronous, and he will never get the new state value in the next line

Comment: no, `setState` is sometimes asynchronous. Wrap the code in `setTimeout` and it miraculously works

Comment: Here is an old github issue about this. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8565

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition.

This means, your set state call will be executed asynchronously.

So in this line, you'll all the time, no matter what you do, get the old state `passwordInvalid` value

```
this.passwordValidator(this.state.email);
if (this.state.passwordInvalid) {
```

As an alternative, you can make your `passwordValidator` returns a boolean,
then you set it into state after you work with it. example:

```
mySubmitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const isPasswordValid = this.passwordValidator(); // will get state value automatically then calculate if its valid
  this.setState({ passwordInvalid: isPasswordValid });
  if (isPasswordValid ) {
    alert("Email: '" + this.state.email + "' is invalid.");
  }
  else {
    alert("Email address submitted: " + this.state.email);
  }
}
```

Comment: a pending transaction can be performed synchronously. You can get new state in after `setState` in some cases.

Comment: The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) says the contrary, rather, you can give setState a callback argument

Comment: have you read this part: "setState() does **not always** immediately update the component. It **may** batch or defer the update until later"?

Comment: Yes, but this will not stop the execution of your handler untill the state is updated then resumes with a new fresh value

Comment: it will stop the execution till the state is updated

Comment: setState actually requests a re-render with a new value, it does not change the value then continue execution. So every single setState will cause a re-render, your component may change a lot of state values, then requesting many re-renders, react may batch them.

Comment: yes, `setState` request a rerender but the rerender can be done synchronously. And if it does it synchronously, you'll get new state value immediately after `setState` call.

Comment: So what it the problem with the question's code ? why it isn't working ? until we `capture` the value before going async ?

Comment: in react v16 in event handlers `setState` delays state update. But there are other cases when v16 rerenders within `setState` call.

Comment: Then please make this code working [in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-frost-7xnpo) without passing the whole code as a callback to the state update.

Comment: Like this, you moved all your your logic to setTimeout, which is asynchronous. Requesting the value of the state right after the timeout will display [the flaw](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-worker-un70b)

Comment: I'm sorry but in your link https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-worker-un70b there's just my code unchanged. There's nothing extraordinary with `setTimeout` being asynchronous - event handlers are also called asynchronously. As you can see in v16 `setState` works synchronously in timers. That's it.

Comment: Event handlers are fired on-demand. wrapping it in a timeout treats you send logic as a callback of the web apis execution in the browser (timer), that will have to wait until the stack is empty. I added a timeout of 200ms and to console.log rather than 0, type first and then notice [what happens](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-cohen-eq4rr).

Comment: We may say, But with 0 timeout it's working fine, it's fine because the stack is empty. now if we are subscribed to some websokcet events that may come at any time, they will surly capture the old state value. in this example it's a simple input value, but it may be the cart of some chat messages.

Comment: This sandbox is not production-ready code. The purpose of the sandbox was to prove that `setState` can rerender synchronously. If you still stand on point that `setState` is always asynchronous then whatever. Bye.

Comment: like you said, `it miraculously works`. we simply just uncovered that this miracle depends on a small use case of React and luck and it's against the docs best practices. Happy coding :)

Comment: The whole point of this discussion was to make you realize that this sentence *This means, your set state call will be executed asynchronously* is not true. Should be *set state call **may** be executed asynchronously*.

Comment: Yes, based on luck (nocontext & empty stack). And nobody will go to production with this.

Comment: :)) React is production ready with its `sync/async` `setState` behavior.